# Can I disable Windows Server 2008 R2 Customer Experience Tasks?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

Can I disable the *CEIP* and *Application Experience Tasks* in the task scheduler without hesitation?

I'm talking about:

```
\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience: 
      "AitAgent" and "ProgramDataUpdater"
\Microsoft\Windows\Autochk: 
      "Proxy"
\Microsoft\Windows\Customer Experience Improvement Program: 
      "Consolidator", "KernelCeipTask" and "UsbCeip"
\Microsoft\Windows\Customer Experience Improvement Program\Server:
      "ServerCeipAssistant", "ServerRoleCollector" and "ServerRoleUsageCollector"
```